# How to delete email account from Android 5.0.2

Tags: applications

I am not able to delete my outlook account from the android. It is Lenovo A6000.
I want to add my work email address instead of outlook.com

I have already added my work email address however I am not able to delete the outlook account.

I have tried pressing the bottom left key but it does not give the option to delete the account.

Comment: Post screenshots.

Comment: Usually you can delete your accounts in your mail application - otherwise go into the settings menu - accounts and remove it from there